# Ensuring that MS Word margin settings meet provided requirements

Tags: typography, page-layout, print-production, microsoft-word, margin

I've the following set of requirements with respect to the document margins:

> - 4cm binding margin
> - 2cm head margin
> - 2.5cm fore-edge
> - margin 4cm tail margin

How to ensure that MS Word settings reflect the requirements above. My current settings are:

[image: MS Word margin settings - page 1]
[image: MS Word margin settings - page 2]

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - please look through [tour] to get a sense of our community - who we are and what we are about. Then look over [ask] and [answer] a question, to see what makes a good query here and how best to frame it. As initially posted your actual question is unclear, as is what research you've done yourself thus far. Could you perhaps edit for clarity of question, and show or tells us what you've done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minute or so of google-fu leads to:

> Text layout:
>           4cm binding margin
>           2cm head margin (top of page)
>           2.5cm fore-edge margin (the bit your thumb is against if
>                   you're riffling through the pages)
>           4cm tail margin (bottom of page)
>          Print on one side of the paper.
>           Use no less than 1.5 spacing, with quotations and notes
>                   single-spaced.
>  
>           Pagination continuous, to include any pages with just diagrams,
>                   tables, illustrations, etc.

From source: http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/diss/docs/doc_thesis_layout.html

Which I think clarifies a bit for you the meaning of the terminology of your requirements, which should allow you to easily meet them, even in Microsoft Word!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much, I've did that. It just doesn't feel right to me as the top margin feels too narrow. Also there are settings for `multiple pages` option; I'm not sure whether *normal* is the right one.

Comment: In MS Word terminology, I think you want "mirror margins" which all real page layout apps call "facing pages" or "spreads" - this should give you the controls you need to set a central binding margin & gutter which differ from the "fore-edge margin".